# React - two different Switch

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-router

I have created two different Switch from `react-router-dom`. One main Switch have all main Routes with MainTemplate and now I want to add different Route without this MainTemplate to have blank page. Is there any way to do this with React Router Dom ?

```
return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <BrowserRouter>

        // Different page for login without MainTemplate UI
        <Switch>
          <Route strict exact path="/login" component={LoginPage} />
        </Switch>

        <MainTemplate>
          <MenuSidebar />
          <NextMeet />
          <Suspense
            fallback={
              <div style={{width: '100%', height: '100%', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
                <h1>Ładowanie...</h1>
              </div>
            }
          >
            // Main Switch for the rest of an app
            <Switch>
              <PrivateRoute exact path={routes.home} component={Home} />
              <PrivateRoute exact strict path={routes.timetable} component={Timetable} />
              <PrivateRoute exact strict path={routes.topicDatabase} component={TopicDatabase} />
              <PrivateRoute exact strict path={routes.history} component={History} />
              <PrivateRoute exact strict path={routes.account} component={Account} />
            </Switch>
          </Suspense>
        </MainTemplate>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>
  );
```

For now when I go to `'/login` I see LoginPage component and also `MainTemplate, MenuSidebar and NextMeet components`

Comment: I would make one Component to switch between these two login pages based on prop passed while redirecting (prop would tell if previos site was MainTemplate or not). And you don't need two switches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, you should only have one `<Switch>` on this page. So, since `Login` doesn't require `<MainTemplate>`, this should be moved into a new component. Then, link to that component it's own `<Route>` (Aafter `login`) as a "catch all" for `path="/"`.

Then, in your new page you made for the `Main` page, you can use the subroutes you have on that page.

Updated Page

```
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <BrowserRouter>

        // Different page for login without MainTemplate UI
        <Switch>
          <Route strict exact path="/login" component={LoginPage} />
          <Route path="/" component={MainPage} />
        </Switch>


      </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>
  );
```

New "`main-page.component.jsx`

```
        <MainTemplate>
          <MenuSidebar />
          <NextMeet />
          <Suspense
            fallback={
              <div style={{width: '100%', height: '100%', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
                <h1>Ładowanie...</h1>
              </div>
            }
          >
            // Main Switch for the rest of an app
            <Switch>
              <PrivateRoute exact path={routes.home} component={Home} />
              <PrivateRoute exact strict path={routes.timetable} component={Timetable} />
              <PrivateRoute exact strict path={routes.topicDatabase} component={TopicDatabase} />
              <PrivateRoute exact strict path={routes.history} component={History} />
              <PrivateRoute exact strict path={routes.account} component={Account} />
            </Switch>
          </Suspense>
        </MainTemplate>
```

Comment: Yeah, I was wondering that I would need to do this... I was thinking that there is one simpler way to do this :) Thanks for the answer

Comment: Happy to help :) (If it solves your problem, please accept the answer :D

Comment: Yup I need to wait 5 more minutes to do this :)